# PostgreSQL using sum in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sum

I have a table which has a numeric column named 'capacity'. I want to select first rows which the total sum of their capacity is no greater than X, Sth like this query

```
select * from table where sum(capacity )<X
```

But I **know** I can not use aggregation functions in `where` part.So what other ways exists for this problem?

Here is some sample data

```
id| capacity
1 | 12
2 | 13.5
3 | 15
```

I want to list rows which their sum is less than 26 with the order of id, so a query like this

```
 select * from table where sum(capacity )<26 order by id
```

and it must give me

```
id| capacity
1 | 12
2 | 13.5
```

because 12+13.5<26

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample.

Comment: try the having clause

Comment: @Mureinik I added some sample data.thanks

Comment: @HaleemurAli What columns should I add in group by part?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want here, but this is my best guess: You want to select rows from the table in order of the id column, summing up capacity as you go and stop selecting before the sum reaches 26?

Comment: @DavidBachmannJeppesen yes this is exactly what I want and seems Mureinik's answer is the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the window variant of `sum` to produce a cumulative sum, and then use it in the `where` clause. Note that window functions can't be placed directly in the `where` clause, so you'd need a subquery:

```
SELECT   id, capacity
FROM     (SELECT id, capacity, SUM(capacity) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS cum_sum
          FROM   mytable) t
WHERE    cum_sum < 26
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: in first select capacity should not be cum_sum?

Comment: @MajidHojati In the sample you gave in the question, you want to display the capacity per row, not the cumulative capacity, so that's what I put in the select list. You could, of course, either add `cum_sum` or replace `capacity` with it - it all depends on what result you want to display.

Comment: Not sure cum sum is the best naming for this :P

Answer (score 10):

A bit late to the party, but for future reference, the following should work for a similar problem as the OP's:

```
SELECT id, sum(capacity)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING sum(capacity) < 26
ORDER by id ASC;
```

Use the PostgreSQL docs for reference to aggregate functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-agg.html

Answer (score 5):

Use `Having` clause

```
    select * from table order by id having sum(capacity)<X
```

Comment: I used this but it say's 'ERROR: column "id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 8'  id is its primery key

Comment: see the edits.When i wrote the answer you only provided the first snippet.So,after your edit i also modified the answer

Comment: I have no idea why your answer gives me that error again, but Mureiniks answer does not